# How to get user_pseudo_id equivalent in the unity app from firebase sdk?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

From Firebase, `user_pseudo_id` is logged to Bigquery. I am trying to get the matching value to those user_pseudo_ids from the unity project that uses Firebase SDK. `FirebaseAnalytics.GetAnalyticsInstanceIdAsync()` does not seem to execute in Android devices.

I tried `GetAnalyticsInstanceIdAsync` using `FirebaseAnalytics` as follows:

```
public Task<string> DisplayAnalyticsInstanceId()
    {
        return FirebaseAnalytics.GetAnalyticsInstanceIdAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.Log("App instance ID fetch was canceled.");
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.Log(String.Format("Encounted an error fetching app instance ID {0}",
                                        task.Exception.ToString()));
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log(String.Format("App instance ID: {0}", task.Result));
            }
            string user_pseudo_id = task.Result;
            return task;
        }).Unwrap();
}
```

When I run the project on Windows, I get `App instance ID: FakeAnalyticsInstanceId0` in the debug log. However, when I build as an apk and test it on my andriod device it does nothing as if `public Task<string> DisplayAnalyticsInstanceId()` never executes. I tried displaying the result on the screen of the phone which does not show up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do get your problem, check your Android manifest, Past Project Package name in to the Unity3d Build Settings and in manifest from firebase project console and it will work in Android too.

we can do that easily with user Authentication and checking every user id that they are using Firebase or not by simply adding of user in realtime fireabse Database, which also work offline too.

Do let me know if you need more help, Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like the problem is I need to add some permissions to Andriod manifest. Everything else checks out.

Comment: Yes, did you get the permissions?

Comment: Yes, added <uses-permission andriod:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to the Android manifest file and it worked.